# sr() and sr1() and the difference between them

Tags: scapy

Does anybody know what is the difference between these two methods?
they are both sending one packet, and getting answers from the IP they sent it to.

In addition, I didn't really understand what is the meaning of these parameters:
promisc, iface, nofilter

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Absolutely, and that anybody is [the scapy documentation](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#send-and-receive-packets-sr) =)

Answer (score 2):

In the context of the Python Scapy library, `sr()` and `sr1()` are both functions used for sending and receiving network packets, typically in the context of network reconnaissance, packet crafting, and analysis. The main difference between them is in how they handle responses and the return values.

1. `sr()` (Send and Receive):

   - `sr()` is used to send packets and receive responses.
   - It sends a packet and waits for responses, and it returns a list of two lists: one containing the sent packets and the other containing the received packets.
   - This function is often used when you want to send a packet and capture multiple responses, such as during network scanning.

Example:

```py
answered, unanswered = sr(IP(dst="192.168.1.1")/ICMP())
```

In this example, it sends an ICMP packet to the IP address 192.168.1.1 and captures both answered and unanswered packets.

2. `sr1()` (Send and Receive One):

   - `sr1()` is used to send a packet and receive a single response.
   - It sends a packet and waits for a single response, and it returns the first response packet received.
   - This function is often used when you only expect one response, and you want to access that response directly.

Example:

```py
response = sr1(IP(dst="192.168.1.1")/ICMP())
```

In this example, it sends an ICMP packet to the IP address 192.168.1.1 and captures the first response packet.

In summary, the main difference is that `sr()` returns a list of sent and received packets, while `sr1()` returns the first received packet. The choice between them depends on your specific use case and whether you are interested in multiple responses or just one.